# How to disable desktop switch on fullscreen

Tags: release-loki, desktop, window-management

I'm on Loki and every time I turn on fullscreen mode for one of my applications like Chrome or atom, the fullscreen window moves to a new desktop.

Is there any way to stop this and just stay on the current desktop?

Cheers,
FL

Answer (score 6):

You can deactivate this feature by disabling dynamic workspaces in gala preferences.

Open dconf Editor, if you have it, and go to `org` -> `pantheon` -> `desktop` -> `gala` -> `behavior` and untick `dynamic-workspaces` point.

[image]

Or just run follow command in the Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false
```

---

To revert this feature back tick `dynamic-workspaces` point again or run `gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces true` in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would solve the problem but also (obviously) turn off dynamic workspaces which I prefer over static ones. Is there no way to tell gala to just not create a new workspace in this specific case?